# Excel conditional formatting formula to highlight row if a cell contains a text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting

I'm trying to highlight rows when a cell value contains a text I specify.

This is what I have so far:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yes",B:B))
```

and this is the sheet

```
a   yes 43
b   no  2
c   maybe   43
d   ok  7897
e   yea 21
f   hmm 6
g   oo  1
h   noo 6
i   yaa 1
j   yea 85
k   hmm 8
l   yes 8
```

The result I want is the first and last row to be highlighted since they both contain the word "yes" at the second column.

Thanks

Comment: instead of `B:B` use `B1`  Excel will iterate the row number

Comment: If you use SEARCH then cells will be highlighted if they contain "yes" even in other text, so "yesterday" or "Hell Yes!" would be formatted - is that your requirement?

Answer (score 2):

To highlight entire Row in your case, you need to select both Columns, and assign this formula =$B2 = "yes", instead of the Formula you have applied earlier.

Just check the Screen Shot, it's highlighted Rows.

[image]

**I do believe this Solution work for you, in case it differs just  make a comment I'll alter the Solution.**

Comment: Congratulations.  This answer is well done and a *huge* improvement over your previous approaches. A minor point - if Scott's comment came first, a brief mention of it would be good form.  I'll give you an upvote just for the increase in value of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bandersnatch ,,, for encourage to do better & better.

Comment: @Bandersnatch, sometimes my Formula gets wider, so to adjust it how can add Horizontal Scroll Bar below it? I've seen with few of the same kind.

Comment: If the formula is formatted as code (grey background) horizontal scrolling is built in. Just click and drag with the mouse.